# How to get the value of a webservice response in soapUI?

Tags: java, web-services, soapui

I have 2 depending steps in `soapUI`. I want to automatically use a value returned in the 1st response for the 2nd request.

I can make reference to the whole 1st response by using `${FirstStep#Response}`.
But how to continue?

Assuming the response is as follows and I want to extract the value of tag `Key`:

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <s:Body>
      <LoginResponse xmlns="http://schemas/WebServices">
         <Key>asdasdasd</Key>
      </LoginResponse>
   </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use property expansion, like so:

```
${FirstStep#Response#//*:Key}
```

Perhaps have a read through the [documentation](http://www.soapui.org/Scripting-Properties/property-expansion.html).

Answer (score 2):

There are 2  way :
1. Use context reference

```
e.g `context.expand( '${RestTestStep#Response//xpathToDataNeeded}')`
```

2. You can get the whole response and parse it using `XmlSlurper`.

```groovy
def responseXml = testRunner.testCase.testSteps["StepName"].testRequest.response.getResponseContent();
def xmlSlurperObj = new XmlSlurper().parseText(responseXml );
def xmlSlurperObj= new XmlSlurper().parseText(xml).declareNamespace(s:"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/");
log.info xmlSlurperObj.Body.LoginResponse.Key.text();
```

Very good link to learn [XmlSlurper](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Reading+XML+using+Groovy's+XmlSlurper)